# Getting individual joint positions in openni_tracker

Tags: openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have [openni_tracker](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_tracker) running and publishing at `/tf`. I get following type of data if I try to publish `/tf` or save it in `rosbag` or text file.

```
transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1395050118
        nsecs: 781445267
      frame_id: /openni_depth_frame
    child_frame_id: /left_hand_1
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: 2.29258546773
        y: 0.40955856152
        z: 0.746916322515
      rotation: 
        x: 0.499999999997
        y: 0.500001836603
        z: 0.499999999997
        w: 0.499998163397
---
transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1395050118
        nsecs: 781469499
      frame_id: /openni_depth_frame
    child_frame_id: /right_shoulder_1
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: 2.45040462809
        y: -0.0277115992896
        z: 0.594173250142
      rotation: 
        x: 0.713314685492
        y: 0.667630701545
        z: 0.17342876346
        w: -0.123991410271
//--- and so on!
```

How can I subscribe to individual joints position, e.g. to only `right_shoulder_1`? I tried `/tf/right_shoulder_1` but it didn't work. Shouldn't I be able to get even the translation of a joint? For example `/tf/right_shoulder_1/translation/x` should give me x translation position of `right_shoulder_1`.

The data saved together with all joints makes it difficult to use. I also need individual joint data in inside a program.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141261/getting-individual-joint-positions-in-openni_tracker/) by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2014-03-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `/tf` data isn't really designed to work like a normal topic. You don't typically just subscribe to it. More about how `/tf` data works can be read on the [tf wiki page.](http://wiki.ros.org/tf)  Here are 2 simple solutions for you to consider:

1. You could write a node that creates a `TransformListener`, and then in some callback (maybe from a [Timer](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Timers)) you lookup the transform from some frame attached to the depth sensor (maybe `/<camera>_depth_optical_frame`) to the frame at the joint you are interested in.  This transform could then be converted into some other message type (maybe a [PoseStamped](http://wiki.ros.org/geometry_msgs)) and published on some other topic.  Or it could be directly worked with to do whatever you want.
2. You could edit the `openni_tracker` source code to publish a message that contains the data you want.  I have a  package that I worked on a few years ago that does this for all of the skeleton tracking data.  [Here is the package](https://github.com/jakeware/skeletontracker_nu) and here are the [associated message definitions](https://github.com/jakeware/skeletonmsgs_nu).  You might also want to look at the [pi_tracker](http://wiki.ros.org/pi_tracker) package as I think they do something very similar.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2014-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on 2014-03-18**:
Thanks sir. Seems like I was pretty much away from my target. Looking into /tf details.